# how to get the total count of rows

Tags: nhibernate

from my previous question: [multiple results in a single call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947026/multiple-results-in-a-single-call)

**how would I get the count of all articles in a given category?**

I prefer criteria query if possible (would love it if you could show me how to do it in both criteria and hql)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use projections.

I believe, you'll have to create a criteria which will look something like this:

```
ICriteria crit = mySession.CreateCriteria (typeof(Article));

crit.Add (Restrictions.Eq ("Category", someCategory));

crit.SetProjection (Projections.Count("somePropertyNameOfArticle"));

int result = crit.UniqueResult<int>();
```

Comment: +1 you could do a Projections.RowCount (i.e. count(*)) here since we're not grouping by anything.